# Perl CGI reading both url_param and param reliably

Tags: perl, url, cgi, param

I'm writing a function that will list once all params passed to a CGI script, whether it be through a form sent with POST, the URL string, or both.

There are two functions for this:

`param()`: Despite the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI), I have found this to read **EITHER** POSTed parameters from a form **OR** URL params only if there are no POST params.

On the other hand, `url_param()` will ever **ONLY** read params passed in through the URL string regardless of POST.

---

My function

```
sub post_and_url_param_keys{
  if(url_param){
    return [url_param, param];
  }else{
    return [param];
}
```

It can list all parameters if passed in with:

**√** POST and URL params

**√** POST params only

**X** URL params only (lists each key twice)

Is there a way to neatly fix this without having to check the name and value of each and every param pair for duplicates?

Comment: Why aren't you using CGI.pm? Even if you don't want to use it, you can still read the source to see how it does the same thing.

Comment: If you migrate your deployment from CGI to PSGI, [`parameters` in `Plack::Request`](http://p3rl.org/Plack::Request#parameters) gives you both GET and POST.

Answer (score 5):

A slightly improve method would be to check if `request_method() eq 'POST'`. You may still get duplicate parameter names if you query string and post both contain the same parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

Having examined the [code for the CGI module](https://metacpan.org/source/MARKSTOS/CGI.pm-3.59/lib/CGI.pm), I can see nowhere that the QUERY_STRING environment variable is examined for a POST request apart from a statement on line 670 that is meant to be uncommented if the data from the POST data and the query string should be combined.

I would suggest that either this line has been uncommented in your copy of CGI, or the values in the POST data are duplicated to the URL somewhere else - perhaps the browser?